# If statement +isblank in excel nesting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to write an excel formula for below :

- **A1**: has a value 1
- **A10**: has a value as =today()
- **B1** : has a date like 2024-01-12

In A2, i want to write a formula that if A2 is empty cell right now then check if b1=a10 then copy a1 value in a2 else dont do anything.

i have tried if+isblank but keep getting error.

i have tried below but doesnt yield results

```
=IF(ISBLANK(a2),(IF($B1=$A$10,$a$1,"")),"")
```

or

```
=IF(ISBLANK(a2),"",IF(b1 = A10, a1, ""))
```

Comment: I think you mean if `A1` is empty, no?  A formula can't reference the cell it resides in.

Comment: this part doesn't make sense:  **in A2, i want to write a formula that if A2 is empty cell right now**. By definition if `A2` has a formula, it isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on, so this answer might address a question you didn't mean to ask...

It sounds like you want A2 to start blank, then change when A10 = B1, then never change, all via formulas. In other words, a formula that only runs if its cell's current value is blank.

Unless you're willing to explore VBA, I think you won't be able to get what you want. (I'd LOVE to be embarrassingly wrong, here! Anyone?)

However, depending on your situation, perhaps you might instead create an ugly, "only for data entry" sheet containing a log of Value/Datetime values, and then a summarizing tab showing unique dates (or dates of interest) plus the first value in the log per each date? This way,

- you actually have a more detailed and useful set of data that you are summarizing from, and
- your process is less at risk from you being out sick, your computer overheating, or some other outage on any particular date.

Comment: If I'm reading your question wrong, your best bet Is to close this question, then ask again with more detail, especially if we're talking about an ongoing table, not just row 1 and row 2.